# Need to find min, max, range, and average in a list of user inputs but I can't use the built in functions to find them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find the minimum, maximum, range, and average of a list of user inputs, however I can't use the built in min(), max(), or range, built in functions and instead have to find them using iteration. I got the average one to work but I can't get the others to work.

```
def average():

    number_of_stats = int(input('How many stats are being averaged?:  '))

    stat_sum = 0

    for i in range(number_of_stats):

        stat_score = int(input('Please enter the stats #%s:  ' % (i+1)))

        stat_sum += stat_score

    stat_average = stat_sum / number_of_stats

while True:

    conduct_average = input('Do you need to average some stats?   ').lower()

    if conduct_average == ('yes'):

        average()

    else:

        break
```

Comment: I would recommend using lists because it has many built-in functions like `max()` `sum()`, `min()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

for the minimum and maximum values, you can iterate over list and compare each value to a running minimum/maximum. E.g.:

```py
min_value = None
max_value = None

for i in range(number_of_stats):

    stat_score = int(input('Please enter the stats #%s:  ' % (i+1)))

    stat_sum += stat_score
    if min_value is None or stat_score < min_value:
        min_value = stat_score
    if max_value is None or stat_score > max_value:
        max_value = stat_score
```

Comment: Thank you, it is returning the max properly but is returning it for the min value as well.